# Javascript status loop

Tags: javascript, loops

Ok, simple thing in javascript that I could not solve even searching on the web. I guess I even found the right thing but could not put on the right place.

This code tells me if a stream is online or offline. But how do I do to the status and keep updating every 5 seconds?

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://xmychannelx.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/livestatus.json?callback=?",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (jsonp) {
            // parse the JSON data on success
            var channel = eval(jsonp);
            liveChannel = channel.channel.isLive;

            if (liveChannel == true) {
                document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = '<p style="color: #00FF00">Online!</p>';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = '<p style="color: #C0C0C0">Offline!</p>';
            }


        }
    });
});
```

Comment: set a timer to trigger your ajax call every 5 secs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example :

```
var myAjaxCall = function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: options.feedUrl,
    dataType: "xml",
    async:options.sync,
    success: function(xml) {
        // todo
    }
};

var ResInterval = window.setInterval(myAjaxCall, 60000); // 60 seconds
```

To Stop:

```
window.clearInterval(ResInterval);
```

Comment: calling setInterval that way is the same as using eval... (Which is considered a bad practice). You should use another function instead (named or anonymous).

Answer (score 1):

use set time out function

```
setTimeout(function(){
  //your function
  foo();
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
function checkStatus() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://xmychannelx.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/livestatus.json?callback=?",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (jsonp) {
            // parse the JSON data on success
            var channel = eval(jsonp);
            liveChannel = channel.channel.isLive;

            if (liveChannel == true) {
            document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = '<p style="color: #00FF00">Online!</p>';
             } else{
                document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = '<p style="color: #C0C0C0">Offline!</p>';
            }
        }
    });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval(checkStatus, 5000);
});
```

This calls the function `checkStatus` every 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds).

Comment: it's working like my code, but isn't looping, maybe it's because the code is in a .js file inside the html? not on the html.

Comment: my bad, i used `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. `setTimeout` calls the function only once, but `setInterval` calls it indefinitely. I already edited my answer with the correction.